# Using RegExp to Replace Form Control Values into String in MSAccess

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba, outlook

I am displaying an email message in Outlook using values from an MS Access form. I would like users to have the ability to modify the message template without having to edit the code, so I am attempting to create templates in plain text format. In text format, I surround form control names with %%. Then in the button _Click event handler of an Access Form, after reading in the text file, I used a RegExp object:

```
Dim re As New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(%%)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(%%)"
re.Global = True
msg = re.Replace(template, " "" & $2 & "" ")
```

to replace (%%)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(%%) with " & $2 & ". The hope was that this will grab the values of the controls from the form.

I then display msg in outlook using

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = emailAdd
    .body = msg
    .Display
End With
```

Unfortunately, " & controlName.value & " shows in the message instead of the value of the control. Additionally, although .Global is set to True, only the first match is replaced.

How can I get VBA to preform a global replace, and fill in the value of the controls?

Comment: 1) Is it that the message is to be made up of text from several controls on your MS Access form?   2) What is the text file and how does it fit in with the process?

Comment: what is contained in the `template` variable? Have you passed `controlName.value` rather than the value by mistake to `template` by surrounding it woth ""?. On your second issue does adding a `.multiline = True` to your regexp help?

Comment: `template` contains a string read in from a textfile, containing text for a form letter. I have attempted to pass in controlName.value, but that does not make a difference. Yes, `multiline = true` solves the second issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're looking for something like the code below.

```
Sub Tester()

Dim template As String, msg As String
Dim re As Object, matches As Object, match As Object


    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    re.Pattern = "(%%)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(%%)"
    re.MultiLine = True
    re.Global = True

    template = "The %%TextBox1%% brown " & vbCrLf & _
                "jumped %%TextBox2%% the lazy dog"

    Set matches = re.Execute(template)
    For Each match In matches
        Debug.Print match, match.submatches(1)
        template = Replace(template, match, Me.Controls(match.submatches(1)))
    Next match

    MsgBox template

End Sub
```

I tested this in an Excel userform with two textbox controls "TextBox1" and "TextBox2"

Comment: Yes, Replace(template, match, Me.Controls(match.submatches(1))) is exactly what I was looking for!