# extract numbers from string in access

Tags: ms-access, module, vba, expression, ms-access-2007

I need help creating a VB code or expression in Access 2010 that will group numbers from a string where each set starts with number 6 and is always 9 characters long.

Example of strings:

1. Order Confirmation # 638917872-001 Partial Order/$23.74  RECEIVED
2. Order Confirmation - Multiple Orders - Order Confirmation#639069135-001/$297.45 - Order Confirmation#639069611-001/$32.08.

I'm using a VB code to remove all the alpha characters but that just leaves me with:

- `6389178720012374` from string 1 and
- `639069135001297456390696110013208` from string 2.

All I care about is the order number that starts with 6 and is 9 characters long. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I know there's an easier way.

Comment: Does it start 6 or #6?

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET Solution:

If you just need the first 9 numbers from your resulting strings you could use String.Substring, ie:

```
Dim numberString as String = "6389178720012374"
Dim newString As String = numberString.Substring(0, 9)
MessageBox.Show(newString)
```

shows 638917872

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

EDIT:

Maybe you would want to use a RegEx - something like this perhaps can get you started:

```
Private Sub Input()
    Dim numberString As String = "Order Confirmation # 638917872-001 Partial Order/$23.74 RECEIVED"
    Dim numberString2 As String = "Order Confirmation - Multiple Orders - Order Confirmation#639069135-001/$297.45 - Order Confirmation#639069611-001/$32.08"

    GiveMeTheNumbers(numberString)
    GiveMeTheNumbers(numberString2)
End Sub

Function GiveMeTheNumbers(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s, "6\d{8}") 'get 9 digit #s begin w/6
    Do While m.Success
        MessageBox.Show(m.Value.ToString)
        m = m.NextMatch()
    Loop
    Return False
End Function
```

Results -
MessageBox1: 638917872
MessageBox2: 639069135
MessageBox3: 639069611

Comment: I do need the first 9 numbers from string 1, however I also need the other set of numbers from string 2 that start with 6.  The end user will not format the subject appropriately and continues to put both order numbers in the subject line as opposed to sending two separate emails. I get 1000's of these emails each month and it's been taking 3 weeks to weed through them for verify orders received. Is there a code or expression to extract string by numerical group starting with 6 and counting 9 characters after?

Comment: I'm trying to use this code but keep getting a Syntax error. I'm using access 2010 visual basic. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a solution in VB.net code per the question tag - If you're attempting to use this in VBA in Access it will not work and you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362848/using-regexp-to-replace-form-control-values-into-string-in-msaccess

Comment: Ah I see. Guess I was to quick to tag VB and didn't realize it changed to VB.net. I wish it did work in VBA because that is exactly what I need. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function ... tested in VB.NET

```
Function NumOnly(ByVal s As String) As String
    sRes = ""

    For x As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1           
        If IsNumeric(s.Substring(x, 1)) Then sRes = sRes & s.Substring(x, 1)
    Next
    return sRes
End Function
```

Little modif for ms-access

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a VBA solution. You'll need to add **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions** to your references.
This will match every 9 digit number it finds and return an array of strings with the order #s.

```
Function GetOrderNum(S As String) As String()
   Dim oMatches As Object
   Dim aMatches() As String
   Dim I As Integer
   Dim RE As Object
   Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   ReDim aMatches(0)
   RE.Pattern = "\d{9}"
   RE.Global = True
   RE.IgnoreCase = True
   Set oMatches = RE.Execute(S)

   If oMatches.Count <> 0 Then
     ReDim aMatches(oMatches.Count)
       For I = 0 To oMatches.Count - 1
         aMatches(I) = oMatches(I)
       Next I
   End If
   GetOrderNum = aMatches
End Function
```